# how to convert stub.GetTxTimestamp() to type string?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to convert the transaction timestamp returned by shim function GetTxTimestamp() to a string that I can print of send as a text response. The function returns the type  ***timestamp.Timestamp**

I have tried type casting it to String, []bytes but none worked. It seems the pointer returned points to a structure or package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction timestamp is a protobuf timestamp data structure, containing integers for seconds and nanos since 1970. One way to print it is to first convert it to a golang Time data structure, which can then be converted to string:

```
time.Unix(timestamp.Seconds, int64(timestamp.Nanos)).String()
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the quick reply! I tried the way you suggested but I am getting a couple of compile errors when I try it like this:

`txntmsp,errN := stub.GetTxTimestamp()
time1 := time.Unix(txntmsp.Seconds, int64(txntmsp.Nanos)).String()`

Comment: This worked. After I imported the "time" package values txntmsp.Seconds and txntmsp.Nanos were recognised:   `txntmsp,errN := stub.GetTxTimestamp()
_ = errN
time1 := time.Unix(txntmsp.Seconds, int64(txntmsp.Nanos)).String()
`